# Django - Which relationship to be used in my case

Tags: python, django

I need assistance in getting this models relationship sorted out. I am new to Django as well as Python

I am trying to build a employee Performance Appraisal App,  below are its models. I have explained my problem in the model (PerformanceAppraisal) itself. I am open for any suggestion I am ok to change all my models.

Edit 1: Changed Foreign key to ManyToManyField for eligibleEmployees in the first model

```
from django.db import models
from employee.models import employee

# Company head will initiate this years appraisal and he will select eligible emplayees

class AppraisalCycle(models.Model):
    period = models.CharField('For The Period',max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField('Description',max_length=255,help_text=('If required mention Short Description for this period'),blank=True)
    eligibleEmployees = models.ManyToManyField(employee, verbose_name='Eligible Employees')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField('Created On',auto_now_add=True,editable=False)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField('Last Update',auto_now=True,editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.period


#Overall Appraisal information will be created for all eligible employees

class PerformanceAppraisal(models.Model):
    """Initially I tried to put foreign key relationship with AppraisalCycle with to_field="eligibleEmployees"  
    but this asked me to give unique=True condition this wont be possible as this will have duplicate when next year appraisal is proposed for an employee
    I thought I can give ManyToManyField relationship but There is no to_field option so I can select eligibleEmployees

    Can you please suggest what I should do here? If you think I should change my model structure Even I am ok with it"""

    appraisee = #Problem Faced here  cannot use ForeignKey with to_field without unique constraint can't use ManyToMany field as well     reviewer = models.ForeignKey(employee, verbose_name='Reviewer')
    period = models.ForeignKey(AppraisalCycle,verbose_name='For The Period',related_name="perf_period")
    overallrating = models.DecimalField('Overall Rating', max_digits=2, decimal_places=1,null=True, blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField('Created On',auto_now_add=True,editable=False)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField('Last Update',auto_now=True,editable=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("appraisee", "period"),)

    def __str__(self):
        appr = str(self.appraisee)
        return appr

RATING_CHOICES = ((0.0,0.0), (0.5,0.5), (1.0,1.0), (1.5,1.5), (2.0,2.0), (2.5,2.5), (3.0,3.0), (3.5,3.5), (4.0,4.0), (4.5,4.5), (5.0,5.0) )
APPROVE_CHOICES = ((1, "Yes"),(0, "No"),(2,"Reject"))

#Employees will create objective and submit for approaval, the rate after the approval, Reviewer will rate then overall rating is calculated published in the above model after everything is completed

class PerfApprObjectives(models.Model):
    appraisee = models.ForeignKey(PerformanceAppraisal,verbose_name='Appraisee',related_name="Perf_Appraisee")
    objective = models.CharField('Objective',max_length=100,help_text=('Max 100 Characters'),)
    Description = models.TextField('Roles/Responsibilities',max_length=2000,help_text=('Max 2000 Characters'),)
    measurement = models.TextField('Measurement Criteria',max_length=2000,help_text=('Max 2000 Characters'),)
    apprComments = models.TextField('Appraisee Comments',blank=True, max_length=3000,help_text=('Max 2000 Characters'),)
    apprRating = models.DecimalField('Self Rating',max_digits=2, decimal_places=1,null=True, blank=True,choices=RATING_CHOICES)
    revComments = models.TextField('Reviewer Comments',blank=True, max_length=3000,help_text=('Max 2000 Characters'),)
    revRating = models.DecimalField('Reviewer Rating',max_digits=2, decimal_places=1,null=True, blank=True,choices=RATING_CHOICES)
    mgmtComments = models.TextField('Management Comments',blank=True, max_length=3000,help_text=('Max 2000 Characters'),)
    mgmtRating = models.DecimalField('Management Rating',max_digits=2, decimal_places=1,null=True, blank=True,choices=RATING_CHOICES)
    approved = models.CharField('Approved',choices=APPROVE_CHOICES,default=0,null=True,blank=True,max_length=1)
    apprSubmit = models.CharField('Appraisee Submit',choices=APPROVE_CHOICES,default=0,null=True,blank=True,max_length=1)
    revSubmit = models.CharField('Reviewer Submit',choices=APPROVE_CHOICES,default=0,null=True,blank=True,max_length=1)
    mgmtSubmit = models.CharField('Management Submit',choices=APPROVE_CHOICES,default=0,null=True,blank=True,max_length=1)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField('Created On',auto_now_add=True,editable=False)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField('Last Update',auto_now=True,editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.objective
```

Comment: In the first model `eligibleEmployees` should be ManyToManyField. One cycle can have many eligible employees and one employee can belong to many cycles. If I understand correctly that is.

Comment: Yes you are right, But having ForeignKey without the unique=True will not allow to have same relationship? Sorry for my little understanding or these relationship :(

Comment: Foreignkey has nothing to do with unique=True. I suggest you take a step back, and read the documentations closely. If the whole concept of database relationships are confusing to you, read a DBMS book. There is no shortcut to database skills.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, will try to read the document. Will it be possible to give some idea on the above question? I hope my question is clear what I want